# Converting polygon into line segment in OpenLayers

Tags: polygon, openlayers, linestring

I have a polygon which should be converted to line segment. How can this be achieved?

I have tried the following code but it didn't work

Here is my code :

```
selectedPointGeom = interactionselect.getFeatures().getArray();
polygeom = selectedPointGeom[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates();

if (polygeom != undefined) {
    lineCoords = polygeom[0].slice(0, -1);
    let exploded_polygon = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(lineCoords)
    });
    lineLayer.getSource().addFeature(exploded_polygon);
}
```

When I add the `exploded_polygon` feature to the line layer it was still adding the polygon only it was not converting to line.

Here I am getting the `selectedPointGeom` variable from the select interaction. When I select the polygon, it should be converted to line segment and get added to the line layer.

Comment: Your code works OK for me.

Comment: yes ,did a mistake to add the linelayer to my map .Thanks @TomazicM